# How To get the Previous selected State of an Element?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function changecolor(event) {
  document.querySelector(".selected").classList.remove("selected");
  event.classList.add("selected");
}
```

```css
.btn-default.selected {
  background: #2f9734;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class=" btn btn-default selected" data-spid="2bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 1</div>
    <div class="btn btn-default" data-spid="3bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 2</div>
    <div class="btn btn-default" data-spid="4bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 3</div>
    <div class="btn btn-default" data-spid="5bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 4</div>
    <div class="btn btn-default" data-spid="6bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This Code is a Prototype.

I can't change the `changecolor` function and Also, the new HTML change can be done via JavaScript. Now how can I get the previous selected state.  Actually I want the previous selected button's `data-spid`.

Comment: you don't want to change the HTML and you also don't want to change the Javascript ?

Comment: @FarooqHanif .. problem statement updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function changecolor(event)
{
document.querySelector(".selected").classList.remove("selected");
event.classList.add("selected");
}

var spids = ['2bhk'];

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".btn").click(function(element) {
        spids.push($(".selected").attr('data-spid'));
        
        if(spids.length-2>=0){
        console.log('previously selected: ' + spids[spids.length - 2]);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.btn-default.selected
{
background:#2f9734;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div  class=" btn btn-default selected" data-spid="2bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 1</div>
    <div  class="btn btn-default" data-spid="3bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 2</div>
    <div  class="btn btn-default" data-spid="4bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 3</div>
    <div  class="btn btn-default" data-spid="5bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 4</div>
    <div  class="btn btn-default" data-spid="6bhk" onclick="changecolor(this)">Default 5</div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just instantiate a variable with initial value as '2bhk' and then update it whenever changeColor() is called.

```
   var previousSpid="2bhk";
    function changecolor(event){
    document.querySelector(".selected").classList.remove("selected");
    event.classList.add("selected");
    previousSpid = $(".selected").attr('data-spid')
    }
```